# Precision in Erlang

Tags: erlang, floating-point, precision

Next code gives me 5.999999999999998 in Result, but right answer is 6.

```
Alpha = math:acos((4*4 + 5*5 - 3*3) / (2*4*5))
Area = 1/2 * 4 * 5 * math:sin(Alpha)
```

Is it possible to get 6?

Comment: You are not guaranteed to get exact results when using floating-point arithmetic. This topic been covered many, many, many times already.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have run into a problem so common that it has its own web site, [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/). The problem is due to the way floating-point arithmetic works in pretty much every CPU on the market that supports FP arithmetic; it is not specific to Erlang.

If regular floating point arithmetic does not give you the precision or accuracy you need, you can use an arbitrary precision arithmetic library instead of the built-in arithmetic. Perhaps the most well-known such library is [GMP](https://gmplib.org), but you'd have to wrap it in [NIFs](http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/nif.html) to use it from Erlang.

There is [at least one pure-Erlang alternative](https://github.com/tim/erlang-decimal), but I have no experience with it, so I cannot personally endorse it.

Comment: This is definitely a must read for anyone doing floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @WarrenYoung Thank you for the info, I did searched and I foun this: https://github.com/tim/erlang-decimal But I'm not sure about if is in active development, but some people have forks with changes and new features.

Answer (score 8):

The calculation is done using standard floating point arithmetic on your hardware.  Sometimes rounding errors show up.

Do you really need 15 digits of precision?

To get a more "exact" value there are multiple options:

```
> round(Area). % Will round to integer
6
```

or you could round to some precision

```
round(Area * 10000000) / 10000000.
6.0
```

If the purpose is to print the value, then printing with the default output for floats give you less precision.

```
io:format("~f~n", [Area]).
6.000000
ok
```

or with a specific precision

```
io:format("~.14f~n", [Area]).
6.00000000000000
ok
```

HTH